# How do I tell Mathematica to assume a symbol is bound to a matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

Is it possible to tell Mathematica to treat symbols as matrices instead of scalars?

For example, instead of getting

```
Solve[r == c*n*r + d, r]
```

> ```
> {{r -> -(d/(-1 + c n))}}
> ```

I would like to see

```
Solve[r == c.n.r + d, r]
```

> ```
> {{r -> Inverse[IdentityMatrix[N]-c.n].d}}
> ```

where `N` is a generic order and, of course, assuming the dimensions are appropriate for matrix operations.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, but also keep in mind that `N` is a protected, built-in function in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Are `c`, `n`, and `d` known matrices?